# Config.ini for pybliometrics Python package inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pybliometrics

I am trying to add the .pybliometrics folder inside the files of a Docker container, as it is essential for the package's functionality. This folder contains the config.ini in which the configuration of the package (e.g. the directories, the API keys etc.) can be found. However I am encountering some issues regarding how and where should this folder (.pybliometrics) should be placed inside the container, in order to be accessible from the Python code that imports the package.

NOTE: There is a method located in pybliometrics.scopus.utils, the create_config(), but I read in the docs that the configuration file needs to be already existed.

I have tried to copy the .pybliometrics folder in the /app/.pybliometrics through the COPY command in the Dockerfile and changed manually the paths in the directories (replaced the C:/path/to/config with /app/.pybliometrics) but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know about docker containers, but the note you gave is wrong. See https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#custom-location